# Помогите расшифровать массив в json

Tags: массивы, json

Те кто предоставляют API для своего сервиса, написали: Что объекты товаров надо передавать в массиве:

```
order[items][][offer][id]
```

Скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот как это в json формате то правильно написать?
Пытаюсь так:

```
{
    "items": [
        "offer" {
            "id": 10309
        },
        "offer" {
            "id": 10310
        }
    ]
}
```

Но получаю ошибку json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

связка `offer - объект` является ключ-значением, а значит надо тоже объединять через `{}`. Да и вообще, это же элемент массива, а значит вдвойне надо его выделять

```
{
    "items": [{
        "offer" : {
                "id": 10309
            }
        }, {
        "offer" :{
                "id": 10310
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

А вообще есть сервисы по парсингу JSON, например http://json.parser.online.fr/  можно ведь ими пользоваться